# Personalizar nome de campo nas mensagens de erro de validação

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, validação, laravel-auth

Estou utilizando o Controlller padrão de autenticação do Laravel 5.2:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Como os nomes estão em inglês, preciso alterar para o português. Já configurei o locale para português, em */config/app.php*:

```
'locale' => 'pt-BR',
```

Alterei o *AuthController.php* conforme segue:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);        
    $correct_names = [
        'name'      => 'Nome',
        'email'     => 'E-mail',
        'password'  => 'Senha',
    ];

    return $validator->setAttributeNames($correct_names);
}
```

Ao criar um usuário, utilizando *http://localhost:8000/register*, o nome dos campos ficam corretos, contudo na página de login, *http://localhost:8000/login*, o nome dos campos continuam em inglês (*email* and *password*).

Alguém pode dar uma dica como resolver isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outra forma de customizar o nome do campo é diretamente no seu arquivo do language, alterando a chave `attributes`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Attributes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines are used to swap attribute place-holders
| with something more reader friendly such as E-Mail Address instead
| of "email". This simply helps us make messages a little cleaner.
|
*/

'attributes' => [
    'email'    => 'E-mail',
    'password' => 'Senha',
],
```

Dessa forma todas os formulários de erro que conterem esses atributos serão renomeados.

Answer (score 4):

O código que implementa o método (função) de validação de usuários, tanto no *login* quando na *criação* de novos usuários, pode ser substituído no arquivo.

O método de validação da tela de *login* é **validateLogin()**, localizado em:

> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

Para substituir esse método, insira essa mesma função no arquivo:

> /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

Com as alterações necessárias, no caso em questão:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $data)
{
    $this->validate($data, [
            $this->loginUsername()  => 'required', 
            'password'              => 'required'
        ],[],[
            $this->loginUsername()  => 'E-mail',
            'password'              => 'Senha',
        ]
    );
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 3):

Essa personalização é bastante simples, você precisará somente implementar mais um array para introduzir as mensagens de erro personalizadas, por exemplo:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ], [
        'required' => 'O campo :attribute é obrigatório',
    ], [
        'name'      => 'Nome',
        'email'     => 'E-mail',
        'password'  => 'Senha',
    ]);        

    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: A forma descrita acima é idêntica a que tenho na pergunta, porém funciona apenas no formulário *register* e não no formulário *login*, quando, por exemplo, deixa-se o campo E-mail e Senha em branco e aperta 'Login', aparecerá o nome do campo como o original do sistema.

Comment: Sei que se alterar a função *validateLogin* no arquivo *AutheticatesUsers.php*, em *Illuminate\Foundation\Auth* e colocar da forma como postou: *$this->validate($request, [$this->loginUsername() =>'required','password' => 'required'], ['required'    => 'O campo :attribute é obrigatório!'], [$this->loginUsername()  => 'Usuário','password'=> 'Senha',]);* vai funcionar.. mas acho que essa não é a melhor saída, alterando o código interno do laravel.... =(